# Where is Magento Homepage file located in File Manager?

Tags: html, magento, ftp

Where to find magento homepage in .html or .xml format in FTP?
I actually want to host my javascripts/ CSS in html itself for better SEO.

Comment: Magento is a database/template system. Pages do not exist as flat html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento's home page is not saved a flat html document, it is a CMS page configured in the admin panel.  To find what page is currently being used, go to;

```
system > configuration
```

From the top menu, then go to;

```
General > Web
```

From the left menu.  Find the 'default pages' block in the main content area and there you will find the name of the cms page being used for the home page.  You can search for this page here;

```
Cms > Pages
```

From the top menu, then search by name.

Note if you have more than 1 store setup in Magento, you may need to change the viewscope when checking the settings in configuration.

Comment: Thanks PixieMedia for info. So how can I track .js and CSS used in homepage...so that I can inline them.